# Keys not showing up in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to re-create an app from FreeCodeCamp, a Drum Machine using React. It needs a few keys but when I put them into the codepen it does not show the keys. I cant figure out why they are not displaying. I've even been following a video online and my code is seemingly identical to theirs but mine does not show the letters ["Q", "W", "E", "A", "S", "D", "Z", "X", "C"] on screen. I have the React 18.2.0 and react-dom 18.2.0 CDN's linked into the codepen as well. Any ideas? Code is attached.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keys: ["Q", "W", "E", "A", "S", "D", "Z", "X", "C"]
  };

  render() {
    const { keys } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="drum-machine">
        <div id="display">
          {keys.map((key, idx) => (
            <Box text={key} key={idx} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Box = (props) => <div className="box">{props.text}</div>;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  background-color: #38ada9;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
};

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="drum-machine" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Did you attach the react app to container? You haven't posted that in code, and it might be a reason

Comment: Code is fine but incomplete: https://jsfiddle.net/L183qg42/

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you missing this part to actual render your app (append at the end of your code).

```
...
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("drum-machine"));
root.render(<App />)
```

And also why you have `id=drum-machine` both in HTML and JSX?. change your HTML to

```
<div id="root" class="container"></div>
```

and your JS to

```
...
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
...
```